# Confused by #define and typedef

Tags: c, typedef, c-preprocessor

```
#define T Stack_T
typedef struct T *T;
```

Then what does `T` in `struct T` mean,the one defined by `#define` or `typedef`?

Answer (score 8):

`#define` directives are substituted early on in the compilation process (translation phase 4, compilation doesn't actually occur until phase 7, these phases and what happens during them are detailed in the standard, section 5.1.1.2).

That `#define` will simply change `T` pre-processing tokens into `Stack_T`.

The effect of that on the `typedef` will be to turn it into:

```
typedef struct Stack_T *Stack_T;
```

Following that, `Stack_T` is defined as a type, a pointer to *another* type of `struct Stack_T`. The `Stack_T` and `struct Stack_T` are two separate things.

Comment: Then what does `Stack_T` in `struct Stack_T` mean after `typedef struct Stack_T *Stack_T; ` ? It looks like dead lock to me..

Comment: No, there is a difference between the _type_ `Struct_T` and the _structure_ `struct Stack_T`. If it helps, you can think of them existing in two different "dictionaries" (for want of a better term).

Comment: So you mean `Stack_T` in `struct Stack_T` doesn't have its own meaning(can't be interpreted recursively),this is weird,really.

Comment: `struct x` is a structure with the `x` tag. `x`, assuming it's been typedef'ed, is an actual type. They're distinct from each other so you can use the typedef to refer to a structure with the tag without clashing.

Comment: As the C committee has always strived for needless syntax complexity, struct tags have their own unique local scope in C, which takes presedence over the scope where the struct is declared. Without that little oddity of a syntax rule, the code wouldn't work (I suspect it doesn't work in C++?).

Answer (score 3):

The preprocessor does only do text-substitutions, so that code would look like

```
typedef struct Stack_T *Stack_T;
```

So every `T` in your code is first replaced to `Stack_T`, and after that your compiler kicks in, sees the `typedef` and uses `struct Stack_T*`.

It might be good to know that `struct Type` and `Type` are only the same in C++, not in C.

Comment: +1 I never knew you could typedef a pointer to a struct with the same name as the struct itself. I agree with @compiler, it's confusing.

Comment: Not really that confusing, `struct x` is a far different beast to `x`.

Answer (score 0):

Since `#define` is processed in pre-compilation and `struct` in compilation, after the pre-compilation you'll have `typedef struct T *T;` looks like that: `typedef struct Stack_T *Stack_T;`

Answer (score 0):

The `T` represents `Stack_T` so, you can read the typedef as:

```
typdef struct Stack_T *Stack_T;
```

so every `T` in your code is replaced as `Stack_T` during compiler compilation.