# difference between typedef and define

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is typedef and #define the same in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666353/is-typedef-and-define-the-same-in-c)
>   [Confused by #define and typedef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389387/confused-by-define-and-typedef)

Is there any difference between the following:

```
#define NUM int

...

NUM x;
x = 5;
printf("X: %d\n", x);
```

And this:

```
typedef int NUM;

...

NUM x;
x = 5;
printf("X : %d\n", x);
```

Both tests compile and run without problems. So, are they equivalent?

Thanks.

Answer (score 23):

There is a difference when you want to create an alias of a pointer type.

```
typedef int *t1;
#define t2 int *

t1 a, b; /* a is 'int*' and b is 'int*' */
t2 c, d; /* c is 'int*' and d is 'int'  */
```

Moreover, `typedef` obeys scope rules, *i.e.* you can declare a type local to a block.

On the other hand, you can use `#define` when you want to manage your type in a preprocessor directive.